# Spring security only for authorization. External authentication

Tags: spring, security, authentication, authorization, external

As title says, i'm developing a web application that receives user authentication infos from an external application. A spring controller of my app gets user info and stores it in session. I want to authenticate this user inside Spring Security and then use his roles to grant/deny access to urls like

```
<intercept-url pattern="/myprotectedpage*" access="hasRole('rightrole')" />
```

I read some tutorials speaking about PRE_AUTH_FILTER and UserDetailsService but i can't get the point. What is the application lifecycle of Spring Security? Which classes are involved?
I need some full working samples.

Comment: could you please give us more details on how you want to authenticate your users? you can implicitly set an authentication token for each user, but i don't know if this is what you want. what does the external application supply?

Comment: I already tried with this code:      List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("u"));
         UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken tok = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password",authorities);
         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(tok);  Values of username, password and role come from external application.

Comment: you can try to add the SecurityContext to the session like this. final HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", context); to make the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter aware of the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement a service that holds the user information.

```
@Service
public class UserAuthenticationInfoService {

    private final Map<String, UserInfo> infos = new HashMap<String, UserInfo>();

    public void addUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo){
        infos.put(userInfo.getUsername(), userInfo);   
    }

    public UserInfo getUserInfo(String username) {
        return infos.get(username);
    }

}
```

your controllers populates the UserAuthenticationInfoService service with the user information which you receive from your external application.

then implement a custom UserDetailsService to acces these information.

```
public class CustomerUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserAuthenticationInfoService service;

     public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        UserInfo info = service.getUserInfo(userName);
        return new User(info.getUsername(), info.getPassword(), info.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

and setup spring security context to use this UserDetailsService (you'll find it in the spring security documentation)

Comment: Thanks, it works but i can't get to work Autowired inside the controller that fills user info. I used a static class instead because i run out of time. What would happen if thousand users do login but never logout? UserAuthenticationInfoService will grow indefinitely?

Comment: take a look at google's guava libraries, it contains a cache builder that allows you to build caches which expire entires based on the last access time or creation time.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tuts out there for the same, just need to google properly.

Anyway the best i have found till date (for almost all spring tuts) is [Krams](http://krams915.blogspot.com) and here's the one for basic spring security.

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html

For Implementing UserDetailService here's the link

http://krams915.blogspot.in/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_5023.html

Some others are :

1. [Spring By Example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-security-webapp.html)
2. [MK Young](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/)
3. [And SpringSource Site itself](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html)

**EDIT**

This is how my own application does the authentication (Please note that i dont use external authentication, I simpply get details from DB but i guess it should not be much of an issue).

My `security-context.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled">
    </global-method-security>

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="permitAll"/> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/Admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPER_USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_SUPER_USER','ROLE_ADMIN'"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1" />
        <http-basic/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
        <remember-me user-service-ref="loginService" /
     </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService">
         <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginService" class="com.indyaah.service.LoginService">
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="authService" class="com.indyaah.service.AuthService" />
</beans:beans>
```

Now as you see i have specified a bean named `loginService` as my authentication provider which is a bean for class `com.indyaah.service.LoginService`.

The code for the same is :
**Pl Note I have truncated unnecessary code**

```
package com.indyaah.service;
..
@Service
public class LoginService implements UserDetailsService {

....

    /**
     * Implementation for custom spring security UserDetailsService
     */
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        logger.debug("Inside get member by username");
        if (userName != null) {
            Member memberVO = memberMapper.getMemberByUsername(userName);
            if (memberVO != null) {
                ArrayList<String> authList = memberRolesMapper.getMemberRoles(memberVO.getMemberId());

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                for (String role : authList) {
                    System.out.println(role);
                    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.toString()));
                }

                if (memberVO.getEnabled()) {
                    User user = new User(memberVO.getUserName(), memberVO.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
                    return user;
                } else {
                    logger.error("User with login: " + userName + " not Enabled in database. Authentication failed for user ");
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Enabled");
                }
            } else {
                logger.error("User with login: " + userName + " not found in database. Authentication failed for user ");
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found in database");
            }
        } else {
            logger.error("No User specified in the login ");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No username specified");
        }

    }
}
```

Note 2 things over here.

1. I get the user details (in my case from DB, yours may be diff.) and put it under a new `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` object which is then returned by the method to spring security.
2. Also the authorities, (which I load separately from DB as per my DB architecture, again your scenario may vary) and pass it to spring security via same User object.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own Custom [AuthenticationManager](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.java?format=ok) and Custom [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java?format=ok). This is simple example but it can give you an idea also for your information this is very sensitive part of security context:)

Simply create beans in your spring_security.xml:

```
<http entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
        use-expressions="true">

        <custom-filter ref="sessionManagementFilter" before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />
        <custom-filter ref="customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
            position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />

        <session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"></session-management>
    </http>


    <beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
            <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="sas"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />

        <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationManager"
            class="my.package.security.CustomAuthenticationManager" />

        <beans:bean id="customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
            class="my.package.security.CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">

            <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
                ref="sas" />

            <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager" />


            <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">

                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">

                    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/main.xhtml" />

                </beans:bean>

            </beans:property>

            <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">

                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">

                    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.xhtml" />

                </beans:bean>

            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="sessionManagementFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="securityContextRepository"
            ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
```

When you implement CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter override Authentication and add your external logic:

```
public final class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response){
CustomAuthentication auth = new CustomAuthentication();

            // set details of current user
            auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
            auth.setAuthenticated(true);
            auth.setUserName(username);

            // set authentication to current security session
            LOGGER.info("Setting authentication into existing security context");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

            // if validation done return generated authentication
            return auth;

}

}
```

Then generated authentication object will be handled by authentication manager:

```
public final class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager#
     * authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final BadCredentialsException badCredentialsException = new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password");
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

        //check if user has valid authentication
        if (authentication == null) {
            LOGGER.debug("Null authentication");
            throw badCredentialsException;
        }
        //Check mandatory fields
        if (!Validator.isValidString((String) authentication.getPrincipal()) || !Validator.isValidString((String) authentication.getCredentials())) {
            LOGGER.debug("Null/blank username/credential");
            throw badCredentialsException;

        }
        //Check if there is any role assigned into user
        if (authentication.getAuthorities() != null && authentication.getAuthorities().size() < 1) {
            LOGGER.debug("No authority found");
            throw badCredentialsException;
        }

        //Validate role
        //IF ROLE VALIDATION REQUIRED YOU CAN HANDLE IT HERE
        boolean authorityValid = false;
        LOGGER.info("Validating user authentication. Total grantedAuth size: " + authentication.getAuthorities().size());
        for (GrantedAuthority g : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
            if (!authorityValid) {
                //Testing purpose one type role available, when exact roles prepared create enum types
                authorityValid = g.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_LDAP_AUTHENTICATED");
            }
        }

        //if none of role matching to required throw exception
        if(!authorityValid){
            LOGGER.debug("User has authority but none of them matching");
            throw badCredentialsException;
        }

        LOGGER.info("Final validation done returning authentication");
        return authentication;
    }

}
```

Then if required you can override default authentication object too,if roles dynamically located here is where you handle:

```
public final class CustomAuthentication implements Authentication {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private transient String userName;
        private transient boolean authenticated;
        private transient Object details;
        private static final transient String ROLE = "ROLE_LDAP_AUTHENTICATED";

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see java.security.Principal#getName()
         */
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return this.userName; //for dynamic username logic here
        }



     //IF ROLES DYNAMICALLY ALLOCATED ASSIGN IT HERE, HERE IS WHERE YOU READ FROM INTERCEPT URL

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see org.springframework.security.core.Authentication#getAuthorities()
         */
        @Override
        public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            auths.add(new GrantedAuthority() {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public String getAuthority() {
                    if (authenticated) {

                        return ROLE;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
            return auths;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see org.springframework.security.core.Authentication#getCredentials()
         */
        @Override
        public Object getCredentials() {
            //TODO: a specific algorithm can be stored
            return userName + " is ldap authenticated user";
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see org.springframework.security.core.Authentication#getDetails()
         */
        @Override
        public Object getDetails() {
            return this.details;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see org.springframework.security.core.Authentication#getPrincipal()
         */
        @Override
        public Object getPrincipal() {
            return userName;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see org.springframework.security.core.Authentication#isAuthenticated()
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isAuthenticated() {

            return this.authenticated;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * org.springframework.security.core.Authentication#setAuthenticated(boolean
         * )
         */
        @Override
        public void setAuthenticated(boolean arg0) {
            this.authenticated = arg0;

        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public void setDetails(Object details) {
            this.details = details;
        }

    }
```