# How to disable spring based authentication but keep role based authorisation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In this application I dont want any spring authentication because Authentication is being done by a SSO service, the SSO sends me the the userId and role

Now, I want to use the role being sent for authorisation. The code to set the role is in the implementation of the UserDetailsService

The problem I have is that the UserDetailsService only gets called if I add formLogin to the security config. And of course I dont want formLogin at all as I dont want authentication. So how can I do authorisation without calling formLogin?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
http
.addFilterBefore(encodingFilter,CsrfFilter.class)
.addFilterAfter(new MdcFilter(), SwitchUserFilter.class)
.addFilterAfter(new ParameterSanitizerFilter(), MdcFilter.class)
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole(StringConstants.USER_ROLE, StringConstants.MANAGER_ROLE);
//.formLogin();
}
```

**** EDIT
Thanks for the help, pczeus' link seems to be the same issue. However still struggling!
I set up a controller on RequestMapping path "/" but it doesnt get fired (the purpose of the controller is to get the role from session and set it in a new UserAuthenticationInfoService - as per pczeus link)

so I need the controller to execute before this line:

```
.antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole(StringConstants.USER_ROLE, StringConstants.MANAGER_ROLE);
```

how can I do it?

Comment: try this, maybe it helps.... http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/89136-need-help-on-spring-security-authorization-without-authentication

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring security only for authorization. External authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366763/spring-security-only-for-authorization-external-authentication)